# setStatusBarColor gradient only

Tags: java, android

this below creates a statusbar, and background from R.drawable.gradient

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        android.graphics.drawable.Drawable background = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Are you able to help me to get only:

```
  getWindow().setStatusBarColor(R.drawable.gradient);
```

Of course dosent work. Any Idea?

Comment: `setStatusBarColor` accepts only color integers and `R.drawable.gradient` is a resource ID of a drawable. If you want to have a gradient behind statusbar you'll need to make statusbar completely transparent then create a dummy view with height of statusbar and gradient background within your activity.

Comment: @Pawel please post your comment as answer so it can be accepted and the question can be closed 